# Internet Explorer adds duplicate param tags to object elements in contentEditable mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, contenteditable, object-tag

In Intenet Explorer (9 version) there is following problem:
Browser adds additional param tags to object element. It's visible in element.innerHTML. 
My code saves resulting html and on next rendering I got bigger html. 
And on all subsequent saves it becomes bigger which causes problems

Initial html:

```
<object width="150" height="150" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
<param value="3968" name="_cx">
...
<embed width="90" height="150" menu="false" loop="false" wmode="transparent" quality="high" src="/flash/helloworld.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</object>
```

Becomes bigger like this:

```
<object width="150" height="150" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
...
<param value="3968" name="_cx">
....
<param value="3968" name="_cx">
.....
<param value="3968" name="_cx">
....
<embed width="90" height="150" menu="false" loop="false" wmode="transparent" quality="high" src="/flash/helloworld.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</object>
```

Comment: So the question is how to prevent this?

Comment: How to prevent this or how to deal with it. Any ideas?

Comment: Afraid not, sorry. Looks like an IE bug/oddity that I haven't seen before. I suggest removing duplicate `<param>` elements before submitting.

Comment: Ended up with this workaround in result. For now.

Comment: Faced the same problem. Any news about this issue?

Comment: No, I used JS code which removed <param> tags